# how can I detect when a checkboc is changed in qcombobox

Tags: qt

I have a **QComboBox** with items where they have a check box (using QStandardItem and item->setCheckable(true))

How can I detect when one of the items has changed it's checkbox value?

Comment: `if(checkbox->checkState() == Qt::Unchecked)`...

Answer (score -1):

To observe `checkState` of item you should observe model but not `QComboBox`. For this purpose you can connect to signal `QStandardItemModel::itemChanged` and look for any changes. But the thing here is `itemChanged` signal emits for any changes not only `checkState`. If you look for only `checkState` changes you need to store *last check state* and compare it with current state when receive `itemChanged` signal. For this purpose you can use *UserRole* of item. Example:

```
//create model
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(4, 1, this);
for (int row = 0; row < model->rowCount(); ++row)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < model->columnCount(); ++column)
    {
        QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(QString("row %0, column %1").arg(row).arg(column));
        item->setCheckable(true);
        item->setData(Qt::Unchecked, Qt::UserRole + 1); //initial set of last state
        model->setItem(row, column, item);
    }
}

ui->comboBox->setModel(model);
ui->comboBox->setModelColumn(0);

//detect checkState changes
connect(model, QStandardItemModel::itemChanged, this, [this](QStandardItem *item)
{
    if (item->checkState() != item->data(Qt::UserRole + 1).value<Qt::CheckState>()) //last and current state are different
    {
        qDebug() << "Checked changed. " << item->checkState();
        item->setData(item->checkState(), Qt::UserRole + 1);  // update last state
    }
});
```

Comment: The provided code doesn't compile. Use `&QStandardItemModel::itemChanged` in call to `connect()`. However i don't think that the solution works because selecting an item won't change it's data and thus `QStandardItemModel::itemChanged` won't be emitted. You might connect to `&QComboBox::activated` or `&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged` and map the index to the underlying item of the model and then change/toggle the item check state based on your requirements.

Comment: @MathiasSchmid About compiling you should be right but for some reason in my case building is well. I'm not sure why it is, it should not be. About item data changing: You don't ask how to change data with `QComboBox` so I supposed you have implemented it already. So my answer is only about detecting of data changing but not how to change data. Sorry for misunderstand. Maybe you need to clarify you question.

Comment: @MathiasSchmid In fact for testing I set the model for both combobox and table (table for editing and combobox for showing). I tried to avoid implementing combobox editing of item checkState because I thought it is out of scope your question.

Comment: Ok, got it. With your additional comments your solution makes sense.